# Relative path not working in PHP

Tags: php, include, relative-path

I am having problems to go up and down in folders using both relative and absolute path. Everything I try giver me an error:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project\Telas\Funcionario\IncluirFuncionario.php

When I try using "dirname(**FILE**)" it returns a warning:

> Warning: include_once(C:\wamp\www\qrFoodManager\Telas\Funcionario/../../Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\qrFoodManager\Telas\Funcionario\IncluirFuncionario.php on line 2

When I try relative paths, it gives me a warning like:

> Warning: include_once(../../Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\qrFoodManager\Telas\Funcionario\IncluirFuncionario.php on line 2

This is the project tree (open on eclipse Helios): http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/5593/y3l3.png

I am trying to include VerificaAutenticacaoSubTela.php in IncluirFuncionario.php; currently using Wamp Server 2.4 installed on C: .. Help please!

Comment: Which file are you trying to include it from?

Comment: I am trying to include VerificaAutenticacaoSubTela.php in IncluirFuncionario.php - which I am using inside an iframe

Comment: What's the warning for `dirname(FILE)`? - you've only posted your code

Comment: Warning: include_once(C:\wamp\www\project\Telas\Funcionario/../../Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project\Telas\Funcionario\IncluirFuncionario.php on line 2

Comment: Why don't you try something like this (assuming the files are in document root) `include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php')`

Comment: needs another `../` ?

Comment: @dbh it returns another warning include_once(C:/wamp/www/Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project\Telas\Funcionario\IncluirFuncionario.php on line 2

Comment: When you say you used `dirname(FILE)` does `FILE` refer to a file location, or did you actually use `FILE`? If so, try `var_dump(dirname(__FILE__));` and that should give you the current location in which you're trying to include from.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

```
<?php include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php"); ?>
```

Comment: No luck ;/

Warning: include_once(C:/wamp/www/Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project\Telas\Funcionario\IncluirFuncionario.php on line 2

Comment: Try include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php");

Answer (score 2):

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/Telas/Seguranca/VerificarAutenticacaoSubTela.php");
?>
```

**Note: ** Assuming the path where the files are is: `/project/Telas` within your `wamp/www`